# how to use pls format into windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I use PLS format on windows phone ? Here's my attempt so far:

```
private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
{
    new AudioTrack
    (
        new Uri("http://mobilehigh.bmradio.de:8080/titel-info", UriKind.Absolute),
        "Windows Phone Radio",
        "Windows Phone Radio Podcast",
        new Uri("shared/media/Episode29.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
    ),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows phone doesn't support the pls format. For Supported playlists see [Supported Media Formats, Protocols, and Log Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Hence if you need to support the pls format you'll have to write support for it by your yourself.